# Python tfcausalimpact: how can I access the p-value?

Tags: python, p-value, attribution

I'm using tfcausalimpact (https://github.com/WillianFuks/tfcausalimpact).

When I run the analysis, I know that I can access the p-value by instantiating the model

`ci = CausalImpact(data,pre_period,post_period)`

`ci.summary()`

But that gives a wrapped-up text summary, and I want to save the P-value as a variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer in the documentation. However, on [this line](https://github.com/WillianFuks/tfcausalimpact/blob/8429e6660de9831e48f5a437fe79c43371908042/causalimpact/main.py#L343) of the source code, the `CausalImpact.summary` method passes `self.p_value` to another function. The [method that computed the p-value](https://github.com/WillianFuks/tfcausalimpact/blob/8429e6660de9831e48f5a437fe79c43371908042/causalimpact/inferences.py#L372) describes it as:

> ...the p-value for the hypothesis testing that there's signal in the observed data... Ranging between 0 and 1, represents the likelihood of obtaining the observed data by random chance.

You can see in the [summary template](https://github.com/WillianFuks/tfcausalimpact/blob/master/causalimpact/summary/templates/summary) that the "Posterior prob. of a causal effect" is computed as `(1 - p_value) * 100)` (and some rounding).

In your code, you should be able to access it programmatically as `ci.p_value`.